# Split angular ui-router named views into modules

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following `state` defined in my `app` module.

`$stateProvider
      .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/',
        views: {
          'header': {
            templateUrl: 'header.tpl.html'
          },
          'content': {
            template: 'Content goes here'
          },
          'footer': {
            templateUrl: 'footer.tpl.html'
          }
        }
      });`

But, I want to put `header` and `footer` in separate angular modules and load them as module dependency. Like - `app.header` & `app.footer`

Since, I can not redeclare a state. And, two states with same url doesn't work. So, is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is a bit old, but I guess answering might be useful as a future ref.
Have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/54) on ui-router GitHub, it seems to me that it could help.

The gist of the thing is represented by the following 2 code blocks:

```
// File1.js
angular.module('myApp').config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state("toplevelfeature", {
            url: '/topleavelFeature'...
        })
        .state("toplevelfeature2", {
            url: '/topleavelFeature2'...
        })
        .state("toplevelfeature.midfeature", {
            url: '/midFeature'...
        })
        .state("toplevelfeature.midfeature2", {
            url: '/midFeature2...'
        })
        .state("toplevelfeature.midfeature.anothernestedfeature", {
            url: '/anothernestedfeature...'
        })
});

// File2.js
angular.module('myApp').config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state("toplevelfeature.midfeature.anothernestedfeature.home", {...
        })
        .state("toplevelfeature.midfeature.anothernestedfeature.detail", {...
        })
        .state("toplevelfeature.midfeature.anothernestedfeature.other", {...
        })
});
```